Manual pivoting without using pivot in Oracle SQL
I have a requirement to pull out data from a table which looks something like below:
SQL> SELECT * FROM weekly_test;

The data to be represented should be manually pivoted and if you notice there is review week 3 missing from the data.
I used the below sql to pivot it:
SELECT CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 1 THEN
          question
       END q1,
       CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 1 THEN
          answer
       END a1,
       CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 2 THEN
          question
       END q2,
       CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 2 THEN
          answer
       END a2,
       CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 3 THEN
          question
       END q3,
       CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 3 THEN
          answer
       END a3,
       CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 4 THEN
          question
       END q4,
       CASE
         WHEN rev_week = 4 THEN
          answer
       END a4
FROM weekly_test;


The result came like above but I want to display for review week 3 the value 'Not Completed' which is currently not possible as the data doesn't exist.
So the question is how can I display all weeks from 1-4 with the question and answer even when the data for that week doesn't exist?

First, to collapse your data down for a proper pivot, you need a GROUP BY on a non-pivoting item that will define your rows (I suggest question, since you appear to want to have a separate row per question), and you'll need to add aggregation (MAX()) around your pivoting conditionally-presented column(s) (here, answer).
For the conditionality you can certainly use CASE as you are doing, but in these situations due to the copy-paste and repetition you might find DECODE more terse and taking up a lot less space.
Finally, you can handle missing values with the NVL function that replaces NULL with something else. Put it all together, and it can be pretty short and sweet:
SELECT question,
       NVL(MAX(DECODE(rev_week,1,answer)),'Not Completed')  a1,
       NVL(MAX(DECODE(rev_week,2,answer)),'Not Completed')  a2,
       NVL(MAX(DECODE(rev_week,3,answer)),'Not Completed')  a3,
       NVL(MAX(DECODE(rev_week,4,answer)),'Not Completed')  a4
FROM weekly_test
GROUP BY question
ORDER BY question


You can use PARTITION RIGHT OUTER JOIN:
with data(rev_week, question, answer) as (
    select 1, 1, 'pass' union all
    select 1, 2, 'pass' union all
    select 1, 3, 'not done' union all

    select 2, 1, 'pass' union all
    select 2, 2, 'fail' union all
    select 2, 3, 'fail' union all

    select 4, 1, 'not done' union all
    select 4, 2, 'fail' union all
    select 4, 3, 'pass' -- union all
),
weeks(rev_week) as (
    select level from dual
    connect by level <= 4
)
select * from (
    select v.rev_week, d.question, nvl(d.answer, 'not completed') as answer
    from data d
    partition by (d.question)
    right outer join weeks v on v.rev_week = d.rev_week
)
order by rev_week, question
;

1   1   pass
1   2   pass
1   3   not done
2   1   pass
2   2   fail
2   3   fail
3   1   not completed
3   2   not completed
3   3   not completed
4   1   not done
4   2   fail
4   3   pass

And then use any PIVOT technique you prefer.

One way to get all the rows needed is using recursive cte to fill in gaps in REV_WEEK column and Cross Join each week with all the distinct questions populating empty answers with 'Not Completed'...
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (REV_WEEK, QUESTION, ANSWER) AS
      ( Select 1, 1, 'pass' From Dual Union All 
        Select 1, 2, 'pass' From Dual Union All 
        Select 1, 3, 'not done' From Dual Union All 
        Select 2, 1, 'pass' From Dual Union All 
        Select 2, 2, 'fail' From Dual Union All 
        Select 2, 3, 'fail' From Dual Union All 
        Select 4, 1, 'not done' From Dual Union All 
        Select 4, 2, 'fail' From Dual Union All 
        Select 4, 3, 'pass' From Dual 
      ), 

   --  Generate number of weeks
   --  One option is using recursive query creating 4 rows of data
   wks (REV_WEEK) AS
      ( Select 1 From Dual Union All
        Select REV_WEEK + 1 From wks
        Where  REV_WEEK <= 3
      )

--      S Q L :
--  Cross Join distinct questions and populate empty answers
Select      w.REV_WEEK, q.QUESTION, Nvl(t.ANSWER, 'Not Completed') "ANSWER"
From        wks w
Cross Join (Select Distinct QUESTION From tbl) q 
Left Join   tbl t ON( Nvl(t.REV_WEEK, w.REV_WEEK) = w.REV_WEEK And
                          t.QUESTION = Nvl(q.QUESTION, t.QUESTION)
                    )
Group By   w.REV_WEEK, q.QUESTION, t.ANSWER
Order By   w.REV_WEEK, q.QUESTION

/*      R e s u l t :
  REV_WEEK   QUESTION ANSWER      
---------- ---------- -------------
         1          1 pass         
         1          2 pass         
         1          3 not done     
         2          1 pass         
         2          2 fail         
         2          3 fail         
         3          1 Not Completed
         3          2 Not Completed
         3          3 Not Completed
         4          1 not done     
         4          2 fail         
         4          3 pass            */

Now you can do any kind of pivoting you like.
One (less used but quite fast) way to do it without PIVOT is using Oracle's MODEL Clause:
--    S Q L :
--  Declare above SQL as another cte - all_data - and use it for modeling
--    S Q L :
Select   Max(Q1) "Q1", Max(A1) "A1", Max(Q2) "Q2", Max(A2) "A2", Max(Q3) "Q3", Max(A3) "A3", Max(Q4) "Q4", Max(A4) "A4"
From    ( Select   QUESTION, Q1, A1, Q2, A2, Q3, A3, Q4, A4
          From    ( Select REV_WEEK, QUESTION, ANSWER
                    From all_data 
                  )
                  MODEL     Partition By ( REV_WEEK )
                            Dimension By ( QUESTION )
                            Measures ( ANSWER, 
                                       0 "Q1", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A1",
                                       0 "Q2", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A2",
                                       0 "Q3", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A3",
                                       0 "Q4", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A4"
                                    )
                  RULES ( Q1[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 1 Then CV(QUESTION) End,
                          A1[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 1 Then ANSWER[CV()] End, 
                          Q2[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 2 Then CV(QUESTION) End,
                          A2[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 2 Then ANSWER[CV()] End, 
                          Q3[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 3 Then CV(QUESTION) End,
                          A3[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 3 Then ANSWER[CV()] End, 
                          Q4[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 4 Then CV(QUESTION) End,
                          A4[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 4 Then ANSWER[CV()] End
                          )
      )
Group By  QUESTION

/*      R e s u l t :
        Q1 A1                                   Q2 A2                                   Q3 A3                                   Q4 A4                          
---------- ---------------------------- ---------- ---------------------------- ---------- ---------------------------- ---------- ----------------------------
         1 pass                                  1 pass                                  1 Not Completed                         1 not done                    
         2 pass                                  2 fail                                  2 Not Completed                         2 fail                        
         3 not done                              3 fail                                  3 Not Completed                         3 pass                       */

OR
if I may suggest to avoid repeting questions (1, 2, 3)...
--    S Q L :
Select   QUESTION, Max(A1) "A1",Max(A2) "A2", Max(A3) "A3", Max(A4) "A4"
From    ( Select   QUESTION, A1, A2, A3,  A4
          From    ( Select REV_WEEK, QUESTION, ANSWER
                    From all_data 
                  )
                  MODEL     Partition By ( REV_WEEK )
                            Dimension By ( QUESTION )
                            Measures ( ANSWER, 
                                       0 "Q1", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A1",
                                       0 "Q2", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A2",
                                       0 "Q3", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A3",
                                       0 "Q4", 'Dummy Answer To Any Question' "A4"
                                    )
                    RULES ( A1[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 1 Then ANSWER[CV()] End, 
                            A2[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 2 Then ANSWER[CV()] End, 
                            A3[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 3 Then ANSWER[CV()] End, 
                            A4[ANY] = Case When CV(REV_WEEK) = 4 Then ANSWER[CV()] End
                          )
      )
Group By  QUESTION

/*      R e s u l t :
  QUESTION A1                           A2                           A3                           A4                          
---------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ----------------------------
         1 pass                         pass                         Not Completed                not done                    
         2 pass                         fail                         Not Completed                fail                        
         3 not done                     fail                         Not Completed                pass                       */

